# How can I test in Django a view which has a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, confirm

I am creating an application in Django and I have a view which receives a form from the html code, and searches in the database if there are any instances of a model whit the values specified in the form.

The problem is that I am new in Django and I don't really know how can I test the functionality of the view (i.e.: if the view's response has a list of values resulting the search of the values of the form in the request).

Here I put the example code of my view:

```
@login_required
def view(request):

# If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = Form(data=request.POST)

    # If the form is valid
    if (form.is_valid()):

        resulting_of_search = ModelA.objects.filter(Q(att1=request.POST[attr1]) & ...)



    else:
        resulting_of_search = []


# Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
# These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
else:
    form = Form()
    resulting_of_search= []



# Render the template depending on the context.
return render(request,
        'url/url.html',
        {'resulting':resulting_of_search} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Django Testing Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial05/)? Essentially, you just need to send a post to your view and test that the response returns what you'd expect.

For example..

```
def test_index_view_with_no_questions(self):
    """
    If no questions exist, an appropriate message should be displayed.
    """
    response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response, "No polls are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_question_list'], [])
```

Taken from the docs. You'd want to change that last line so that you assert that 'resulting' is in the context. Or check that it contains a specific list of results you're looking for. Like this..

```
def test_results(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('ensaioak_bilatu'))
    self.assertQuerySetEqual(response.context['resulting'], [...whatever you expect resulting to contain...])
```

Comment: I did, but my question is: How can I test the result of a view if I have a "return render" at the end of the view?

Comment: And what does mean that "reverse('polls:index')" sentence?

Comment: Reverse is a utility function which can be used to fetch views from a name you give them in your urls file. Docs for it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

Comment: It's best practice to use reverse to allow you to change a URL only once (in the urls file) instead of everywhere you've used it in your codes (including in your tests). However, you can still work without it and simply say self.client.get('**whatever the path for your view is**']).

Answer (score 0):

From reading your answer, I think you are not asking about *unit testing* but just checking whether your view *actually works*. As a start, you can use the code snippet provided on the Django website at the following link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view.